# Running R's C Core Only

Tags: android, c++, ios, c, r

Looking into R, I've seen that there are restrictions to how it could be used in mobile platforms (iOS and Android).

I have seen RInside and RCpp, that let you use C++ for R, which would be great for these platforms, but it seems these are mainly interfaces for R itself, which would still require R to run.

I did notice that there is a big portion of R's core that is in C, and was wondering if it is possible to conveniently use those C functions and structs without running R.

Comment: Seems to me that DIrk and his friend moderators found that the question is too broad. Instead of being pragmatic and taking the question for what it is. The question clearly states if it is possible to use the C core without R itself. This is not a broad question. Either it is or it isn't.

Comment: IIUC, the answer is basically 'yes, as long as your toolchain can compile / build R' -- as long as you have C99 + Fortran(90?) compliant compilers available + required external libraries, you should be able to (licenses permitting). Rmath can also be built standalone. In general, though, most of R's C utilities aren't really modular / disconnected from R's 'core' to be used 'without R', but you might have _some_ luck copying R headers + implementation files you need (note that this will GPL-2 your application)

Comment: @KevinUshey Thanks for your answer. This is certainly more in line with what I was expecting as an answer. Sadly I can't commend you on this through SO's normal means.

Answer (score 2):

No, in general you cannot.

See the [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.rstudio.com/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) manual, and particularly its [section on embedding R](http://cran.rstudio.com/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Embedding-R-under-Unix_002dalikes).

This is however tedious.  Which is why you should look more into [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html).  And yes, I am biased.

Comment: Hey Dirk! From what I've seen, RInside is great, but I've not seen any documentation indicating it would be possible to use RInside in iOS and Android (through NDK). Are you saying it would be possible, without, of course, jailbreaking the devices?

Comment: In short a) there already **is** an app in the Android universe that wraps R, it is called [R Console](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appsopensource.R&hl=es).   And b) you stand no chance whatsoever for iOS as Apple forbids use of the tools needed to build R such as current `gcc`/`g++`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Which is why I was wondering about the R's C Core usage, which would not necessarily require R to run. I might have formatted the question incorrectly.

Comment: See the first line of my answer.  Your premised is wrong.   R needs R to run.

Comment: Thank you Dirk. Given you added "in general" to your response, made me believe there was a possibility. I appreciate your response, but I have to say that promoting RInside seems to be out of place here, given it does not seem to aid the response and adds noise to the answer. Specially when I had already commented on it in my question.

Comment: Disagree. You used a conditional in your question and left it as general.  Had it been a "iOS and Android only" question I would not have bothered to reply.

Comment: Thanks for your comment pointing out where the confusion arose. I have now removed the word that made this question unclear.